# WCF service in Azure throws HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: wcf, azure

I've been working on an Azure app, and added in a WCF service (something I've done successfully before).

It works fine in the stand-alone asp.net application (running in Cassini), but throws a 500.0 error when I try to call it in the AppFabric. I tried publishing it to Azure and hoping for the best, but it then throws a 404 error.

I've set the bindings to basicHttpBinding, no joy. To get round this, I've created a seperate WCF Web Role, which works OK, but I get firewall problems on some machines because it runs on port 8080.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the web.config - I saw a reference that adding `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>` to  `<system.webServer>` might fix it, but it was already present.

The "detailed error info" on the page is:
Module  IsapiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler svcHandler
Error Code  0x800700c1

Any ideas? I'm baffled!

cheers

Toby

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [WCF Azure Known Issues](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure/Wiki/View.aspx?title=KnownIssues&referringTitle=Home) Page? Make sure that you can exclude anything that is listed there, this page already helped me twice.